# Datatables Where clause with two conditions

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I want to select records where p_code=10 & p_code=24 only for the user = 4, in my MySQL Datatables view. I used the following code fragment.

```
$usr = $this->session->userdata('id_user'); 
if($usr == 4)
        {
        $this->datatables->where('tbl_officer.p_code', 10);
        $this->datatables->where('tbl_officer.p_code', 24);

        } else {
        $this->datatables->where('tbl_officer.usr', $usr);
        }
```

But the code outs an empty result. If I remove the line, $this->datatables->where('tbl_officer.p_code', 24); the result shows only the officers with p_code=10.

How can I add these two lines with where clause in my code ? Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `or_where`, so you can get both or one of them:

```php
$this->datatables->where('tbl_officer.p_code', 10)->or_where('tbl_officer.p_code', 24);
```

And you can use `where_in` too:

```php
$this->datatables->where_in('tbl_officer.p_code', [10, 24]);
```

Comment: Never used this but is there a `whereIn` option?

Comment: @vivek_23 yes. there is `where_in`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `or_where` to join both statements, like so:

```
$this->datatables->where('tbl_officer.p_code', 10)->or_where('tbl_officer.p_code', 24);
```

Without it you will just run two separate queries (one for `p_code == 10` and other for `p_code == 24`) and return the value of the last statement.